# how to pass row id in href of a tag in codeigniter controller?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using `jqxgrid` in `codeigniter` to display records from `mysql` `database`. while displaying the data, I made a column named 'action' that contains edit `a` tag to redirect to another page for editing a specific record. I need to assign id to `href` attribute in order to do that. but I can't correctly do that.

In controller, tax.php:

```
foreach($result as $row){
   $data[$i]['tax_id']=$row['tax_id'];
   $data[$i]['tax_name']=$row['tax_name'];
   $data[$i]['action']='<a href="<?php echo base_url()?>/edit_tax/$row["tax_id"];">Edit</a>';
   $i++;
}
```

how can i correctly assign `tax_id` to my `URL`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have to evaluate `$row["tax_id"]` as a PHP expression:

```
$data[$i]['action']='<a href="<?php echo base_url()?>/edit_tax/<?php echo $row["tax_id"]; ?>">Edit</a>';
```

**Edit**: Use PHP's string concatenation to construct the `<a>` element:

```
$data[$i]['action']='<a href="' . base_url() . '/edit_tax/' . $row["tax_id"] . '">Edit</a>';
```

Comment: oh that was a silly mistake, but it doesn't work this way too.

Comment: @HaseebHassy edited my answer, can you try the new one?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do it.

```
<?php
foreach($result as $row)
{
 $editurl = base_url() . 'admin/edit-user/' . $row['tax_id'];
 ?>
 <a href="<?php echo $editurl; ?>" class="edit-user" >Edit</a>
 <?php
}
?>
```

Do let me know if it didn't work.

Comment: it gives : " Forbidden You don't have permission to access /codeigniter/< on this server."
and in url: "http://localhost/codeigniter/%3C?php%20echo%20$editurl;%20?%3E  "

Comment: if you click on this link then it shows this error? or before?

Comment: Do You have admin/edit-user/{:any} defined in routes? If you haven't then and then only it throws error dude

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:

```
$id =  $row["tax_id"];   
$data[$i]['action']='<a href="'.base_url().'/edit_tax/'.$id.'">Edit</a>';
```

It will work properly.